# How to remove any non-alpha characters in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which a column contains names. I want to clean this column by removing all the non-alpha characters.

```
Dataset$name
Jack
Ruby
Kim
*Jack
NA
" "
**Jack
...
```

I want to remove all the non-alpha characters and create a new column such that

```
dataSet$name_cleaned
Jack
Ruby
Kim
Jack
NA
" "
Jack
...
```

What is the best way to do it in R. I have used

Data$name_cleaned <- str_extract(Data$name,"[a-zA-Z]")
But it only gives First letter of the names in the new column.

Comment: Please spend 5-10 minutes searching Stack Overflow before posting a question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I think the question and the solution presented there are different than what I have asked, though, I found what I was looking for in one of the comments. Yes, I did the basic search on google and SO to find out how it is done before posting a question here but could not find out. (Probably I wasnt putting the right words in the search).

Comment: Maybe I misread your question.  What about the duplicate link didn't work for you?

Comment: Its not an exact duplicate, It did sort of give me the pointer what I wanted to do but thats with gsub while I was using str_extract() from stringr package.